# Reading a JPEG in Python (PIL) with broken header

Tags: python, image, jpeg, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to open a jpeg file in Python 2.7,

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open(filename)
```

Which didn't work for me,

```
>>> im = Image.open(filename)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#810>", line 1, in <module>
    im = Image.open(filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1980, in open
    raise IOError("cannot identify image file")
IOError: cannot identify image file
```

though when trying out on external viewers, it opened fine. Digging in a bit, it turns out that the `JpegImageFile._open` method from `PIL`'s `JpegImagePlugin.py` file raises a `SyntaxError` exception due to several extraneous `0x00` bytes before the `0xFFDA` marker in the JPEG's file header,

```
Corrupt JPEG data: 5 extraneous bytes before marker 0xda
```

That is, while other programs I tried simply ignored the unknown `0x00` marker towards the end of the header, `PIL` prefered to raise an exception, not allowing me to open the image.

**QUESTION**: Apart from editing `PIL`'s code directly, is there any workaround for opening JPEGs with problematic headers?

The relevant code from the `JpegImageFile` class which raises the exception appears below, for your convenience:

```
def _open(self):

    s = self.fp.read(1)

    if ord(s[0]) != 255:
        raise SyntaxError("not a JPEG file")

    # Create attributes
    self.bits = self.layers = 0

    # JPEG specifics (internal)
    self.layer = []
    self.huffman_dc = {}
    self.huffman_ac = {}
    self.quantization = {}
    self.app = {} # compatibility
    self.applist = []
    self.icclist = []

    while 1:

        s = s + self.fp.read(1)

        i = i16(s)

        if MARKER.has_key(i):
            name, description, handler = MARKER[i]
            # print hex(i), name, description
            if handler is not None:
                handler(self, i)
            if i == 0xFFDA: # start of scan
                rawmode = self.mode
                if self.mode == "CMYK":
                    rawmode = "CMYK;I" # assume adobe conventions
                self.tile = [("jpeg", (0,0) + self.size, 0, (rawmode, ""))]
                # self.__offset = self.fp.tell()
                break
            s = self.fp.read(1)
        elif i == 0 or i == 65535:
            # padded marker or junk; move on
            s = "\xff"
        else:
            raise SyntaxError("no marker found")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PIL doesn't like corrupt data in the header and falls over as you've discovered.

I've made a pull request to Pillow (the friendly PIL fork) that should fix this problem.

It's not yet been accepted, but hopefully it'll be there for version 2.5.0 due out in a couple of months. In the meantime, you can try it out here: https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow/pull/647

As a workaround, you could use something like ImageMagick to first convert the problematic images to something like png, and then use them in PIL/Pillow.

Comment: Thanks @Hugo! I eventually overcame my problem using OpenCV whenever PIL raises an exception. It's good to know PIL is evolving...